# cx_Freeze : "missing modules" when compiling

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am trying to build a Python application into an exe using cx_Freeze. I have Phthon 3.4 on my machine with Windows 10. I tried the exact process again with Python 3.5 and got the exact same response, so it's not a 3.4 issue. When I build it compiles, but I get the error :

```
Missing modules:
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? ce imported from os
? doctest imported from heapq
? getopt imported from base64, quopri
? org.python.core imported from copy
? os.path imported from os
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from posixpath
? subprocess imported from os
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.
```

Here is my setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import Executable, setup

setup(
    NameError="amazon_pins",
    version="0.1",
    description="my_script",
    executables=[Executable("my_script.py")],
)
```

When I run the executable from my command prompt on the same computer, it immediately closes, with no error messages given. The python script itself runs perfectly.

Any guesses as to what could be causing this?

Comment: How did you install cx_freeze? did you use `pip install cxfreeze`?

Comment: Yes I installed through pip

Comment: More information will be needed in order to help you. If you can provide the code that may help. Otherwise, the error that you are getting will also help. Run your application in a command prompt and make sure you are using the Console base, then report back.

Comment: I added the setup script code. Unfortunately, I don't get any error output when I run the executable, only when I build it.